# Scaling in ViewBox with CEF Browser

Tags: .net, wpf, chromium-embedded

I'm using the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) browser for an application.  I was having some unsolvable Z-Index and memory leak issues with the stock IE-based WebBrowser control, so this was the solution.

Due to some decisions early on, the browser is contained in a ViewBox.  This caused no issues with the IE browser of course, but with CEF, some pretty ugly scaling occurs.  It looks similar to a BitmapScalingMode of `LowQuality`:

[image: Scaling ugliness]

Other than removing the ViewBox, is there anything that can be done to improve the scaling on the browser contents?

Comment: try RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" or RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" on the element inside your ViewBox

Comment: @colinsmith Thanks, but no change.